# random number generator not working properly

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am developing a discord bot, this is a random number generator command and when i use it it returns:
random number from 5 to 10:
35
after a couple fo tries it returns fully rounded
random numbers ignoring the parameters.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'random',
    description: 'returns an aleatory number',
    execute(message){
        let arguments = message.content.split(' ')
        let from = arguments[1]
        let to = arguments[2]
        let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) ) + from;
        message.channel.send(`random number from ${from} to ${to}:\n${result}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: the code doesn't really work at all for me.

Comment: What exactly does `message.content` look like? And what does "fully rounded random numbers" mean?

Comment: This is a really unclear question. Are you expecting to see a decimal? You realise math.floor will always return an integer right? Also, what is an aleatory number?

Comment: message.content returns the entire content of the message that activated the bot, and with fully rounded i mean numbers without decimals.

Comment: with that code you posted, it would be more strange if the numbers WEREN'T fully rounded. `Math.floor` rounds

Comment: You might want to google `Math.floor()` to see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your code a little bit. It helps to convert the numbers to actual numbers.

```js
function execute(message){
    let arguments = message.split(' ')
    let from = Number(arguments[1]);
    let to = Number(arguments[2]);
    let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) ) + from;
    console.log(`random number from ${from} to ${to}:\n${result}`)
}

execute('rand 1 3');
execute('rand 1 3');
execute('rand 1 3');
execute('rand 1 3');
execute('rand 1 3');
```

Comment: Should be `message.content.split(' ')`

Comment: @Elitezen yeah i wasn't bothering to replicate his entire system. I understood that he need to convert a string into a command, and so I did that. It's not like he provided test data or anything.